# Angular's Json.stringify with property problems

Tags: json, angular, typescript, getter-setter, stringify

I'm trying to stringify objects in Typescript that was implemented usign private properties like this

```
export class Foo {
   private _property1:string;
   private _property2:string;
   private _property3:string;

   get property1(): string {
        return this._property1;
   }
   set property1(value: string) {
        this._property1 = value;
   }
   get property2(): string {
        return this._property2;
   }
   set property2(value: string) {
        this._property2 = value;
   }
   get property3(): string {
        return this._property3;
   }
   set property3(value: string) {
        this._property3 = value;
   }


}
```

But when i use JSON.stringfy(), the private properties are read and does'nt go through the get and set methods.

Expected:

```
{
  "property1": "",
  "property2": "",
  "property3": "",

}
```

Received:

```
{
  "_property1": "",
  "_property2": "",
  "_property3": "",

}
```

It is noticed that the property is underlined, but should not, Json should come with the name that was implemented in the getters and setters and not in private properties

Comment: Can you give an example usage on these methods? Where do you use `JSON.stringify` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) only looks at object fields, not at methods or properties (getters/setters).

> If `undefined`, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object)
>
> ...

A getter or setter is defined as a function, and will therefore be ignored in the conversion. Only the private fields of the object will find their way in the `JSON`. And they will only be there, if they are actually initialised.