# Typescript getter field not going through http param

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to send and object containing `name` to my rest api.

```
class Person {
  name: string; // <- This works.
}

const p = new Person();
p.name = 'John Doe';
this.http.post('url..', p ); // sending { name: 'John Doe'}
```

Now, if I try to use setter and getter, it doesn't send the "getter" field.

```
class Person {
  _name: string;
  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value + '!!'; // some additional processing
  }
  get name() { return this._name; }
}

this.http.post('url..', p ); // sends { _name: 'John Doe!!' }
```

How can I solve this? I'd rather not do the following:

- Change my rest api to expect `_name` instead of `name`;
- Create a function to return a "Persistable data" like so:
  `class Person {
    //..
    getData() {
      return { name: this._name };
    }
  }`
- use `setName(name: string) { this.name = name; }` instead of `set`;

Any better ideas?

Comment: Solved by creating a `toJSON` method, which is better than creating own `getData()` that needs to be called manually every time you send it. More info on this: https://cdroulers.com/blog/2015/04/22/typescript-properties-and-json-stringify/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390783/angulars-json-stringify-with-property-problems https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior